# Why the iptable rule can't be listed?

Tags: iptables

To set a iptables rule to drop all packages to input.

```
debian8@hwy:~$ sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

To list all rules.

```
debian8@hwy:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Why the rule added by  **sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP** can't be displayed?

Now to ping my localhost.

```
debian8@hwy:~$ ping  127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
38 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 37000ms
```

It shows that the rule,**sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP** ,takes effect why can't list it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just didn't look at it carefully enough as the answer is right in front of you:

```
debian8@hwy:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
```

You can see `policy DROP` above since you set the chain's default policy to `DROP`.